# Configuring Hue With CDH4.3

Tags: cloudera, hue

I am trying to Configure hue with CDH 4.3.I am facing Configuration Error fo HDFS. Its says that **"Current value: http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:50070/webhdfs/v1/  Filesystem root '/' should be owned by 'hdfs'"**
But in my case the owner root folder is user, So how can i tell hue that the owner of root folder is user.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You can update [DEFAULT_HDFS_SUPERUSER](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/branch-2.3/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py#L42) with 'user' but notice that this is not the official recommended way and it might brake things.

Comment: I also ran into the same issue. I have the Hue 3.5 tarball version and I edited DEFAULT_HDFS_SUPERUSER to my own hdfs user at file desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py  
But still I got the same error FileSystem root'/' should be owned by 'hdfs'. How do I compile this webhdfs.py file so that the changes are effective? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the custom "hdfs-site" on HDFS part,
add the below key-value,

`hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts=*
hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups=*`

Then you should restart the cluster.

I thought may be  `usermod` -a -G root 'user', so the 'user' can get the /root filesystem ACLS, also you need to modify HUE configuration file `pseudo-distributed.ini` to make sure the `Webserver runs as this user` part:

`server_user='user'
server_group='user'`